# Cut a part from a filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-editing, batch-rename

I got files named like this:

```
cam1(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg
cam2(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg
cam3(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg
```

Need to cut `(word1 word2 word3)` and replace spaces with `_`. Renamed files expected:

```
cam1_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg
cam2_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg
cam3_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg
```

In the first pair of brackets there could be different number of "word". Timestamp is always the same.

Comment: is PowerShell ok? In PowerShell you can use regular expressions for renaming. It might be possible in pure batch with a few nested `For /F` loops, or lots of `%FOO:search=replace%` in case the number of possible different words is small, but it would be definitely more ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell allows you to do [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matches so it's easy to do this with [Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *.mpg | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName `
  { $_.Name -replace '(.+?)\(.+?\) \((.+) (.+)\)', '$1_($2_$3)' }
```

You can also shorten the command with aliases:

```powershell
> ls *.mpg | ren -wi -Ne `
    { $_.Name -replace '(.+?)\(.+?\) \((.+) (.+)\)', '$1_($2_$3)' }
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\cam1(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg Destination: C:\Users\cam1_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\cam2(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg Destination: C:\Users\cam2_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\cam3(word1 word2 wordN) (24-04-2012 00-11-13).mpg Destination: C:\Users\cam3_(24-04-2012_00-11-13).mpg".
```

`(.+?)\(.+?\) \((.+) (.+)\)` is a regex that captures the first word and the two date time strings then we'll combine the matched strings together to get the expected output

`-WhatIf` or `-wi` is the option to do dry run. After checking that the new names are valid just remove them to do the real renaming

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) for just this sort of thing. It allows you remove, edit, replace or add numbers to filenames easily. And it does batch files. I use it all the time for renaming photos and video clips as well as mp3 files.

Comment: I need it to run it automatically from scheduler,

Comment: BRU has some very basic command line options, but is not well suited to being run from a scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to a batch file.

```bat
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=(" %%a in ('dir *.mpg /b') do call :DoRename "%%a" "%%b" "%%c"

Goto :eof
:DoRename
  Set SrcFile=%1(%2(%3
  Set SrcFile=%srcfile:"=%

  Set DestFile=%1 (%3
  Set DestFile=%DestFile:"=%
  Set DestFile=%DestFile: =_%

  Rename "%SrcFile%" "%DestFile%"
```

Comment: ZEDA-NL, your script does replace space with _ , however I also need to remove (word1 word2 etc). Those words could be different like (description of event 15) or (this is test). I need to remove that part completely from the filename.

Comment: I didn't realize that the words were different all the time. I modified the script so it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] as suggested by Scott

If you can do a little scripting, I recommend [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) 
You can use a simple regexmatch() 
To do your need full

Here is a sample code

```
Filelist=
Loop, C:\Data\*.mpg ;Assuming your files in data folder
Filelist = %Filelist%%A_LoopFileFullPath%`n
Loop, parse, filelist, `n
{
Renamed := Regrxreplace(A_Loopfield, "\(\w.+\)\s", "_")
Filemove, %A_LoopField%, %Renamed%
}
```

*Test it for few files

Regards
SDK.

Comment: Can you give an example of how something like this could be done with AutoHotkey?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.