# Renaming Parts of Multiple Folders

Tags: batch-rename

I have a large number of folders that contain the video regions on the folders which I would like to remove. For instance, some are PAL such as

/Folder1 [PAL]

Some are NTSC such as

/Folder2 [NTSC]

And some are both PAL and NTSC such as

/Folder3 [PAL][NTSC]

How can I do a batch file rename of all such folders so everything except the folder name is removed? Meaning I only have
/Folder1
/Folder2
/Folder3
etc

With none of the stuff in brackets at all in the folder names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/943130/how-do-i-delete-a-part-of-a-file-name-for-a-batch-of-files-in-windows-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/416785/cut-a-part-from-a-filename-windows-batch

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].